# How do you define logging level with restito StubServer?

Tags: rest, mocking

I would like to show/hide restito's StubServer logging from my log4j config or similar. Any ideas?

Comment: Your question need more context. Can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer in github: https://github.com/mkotsur/restito/issues/14#issuecomment-30337962